# Port iPhone app to iPad as a view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

Is there an easy way to go about this? My iPhone app is in a UITabBarController and every attempt I've made at this so far just results in the app crashing or the tab bar taking up the whole window. I'd just like to be able to have my iPhone app in a 320x480 view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad has a larger screen, which means you have to redesign your app to compensate for the new larger screen, I would not recommend having an app that only uses part of the screen, and I dont know if the reviewers at apple would really like that. When an iPhone app is on the app store users can download the app onto an iPad and the iPad will show that app in a kind of simulator. Users expect that to happen, users dont expect apps for an iPad to only use a fraction of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm going to go ahead and accept this because I've figured it out (figures, right after I post the question!), but to clarify what exactly I was doing: I wanted to add an iPhone app into a small view, because I have a more advanced version of the app on the iPad already. One of the features of it would be to pull up the iPhone version for people to use if they needed to. This will not be going on the market. I fixed it by just manually initializing the UITabBarController and setting the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Neil Inglis has written up an easy trick for porting an iPhone app to iPad. The key thing is that an iPhone app, set up for retina display has an almost iPad resolution. With a little adornment you can do an easy port that looks good.

Have a look at his blog entry ["A little trick for producing a super quick iPad port"](http://www.neilinglis.com/2011/10/15/a-little-trick-for-producing-a-super-quick-ipad-port/).